# Form submission success message not displaying

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a fully working html contact page, with a php email script, with recaptcha 2 - all of these work perfectly.

Previously, the form redirected to the php file, which showed a basic success message. Again, this worked fine.

I've tried incorporating a contact.js file onto the page, and the form submission still works, but the success message in the PHP script isn't being displayed.

I'm an idiot when it comes to JS so that's probably the issue, but any help would be gratefully received.

Here's the HTML, PHP and JS:

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="#" role="form">
   <div class="messages"></div>
   <div class="controls">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="form_name">Name *</label>
                <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your name *" required="required" data-error="Name is required">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="form_email">Email *</label>
                <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your email address *" required="required" data-error="A valid email is required">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="form_phone">Telephone</label>
                <input id="form_phone" type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter a contact telephone number (optional)">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="form_message">Message *</label>
                <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your message *" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Please enter your message"></textarea>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
            <p><div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxxxxx"></div></p>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Submit" onClick="window.location = '#formstart'"></p>
            <br><p class="text-muted"><strong>*</strong> These fields are required.</p>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$sendTo = "email@email.com";
$subject = "New message from email.com";
$headers .= 'From: <enquiries@email.com' . "\r\n";

$name = @$_POST['name'];
$phone = @$_POST['phone'];
$email = @$_POST['email'];
$message = @$_POST['message'];

$okMessage = 'Thank you for your message. One of the team will be in touch as soon as possible.';
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';$url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
$privatekey = "XXXXX";
$response = file_get_contents($url."?secret=".$privatekey."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$data = json_decode($response);
$emailText = "Name: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Email: $email \n Message: $message";

if (isset($data->success) AND $data->success==true) {

    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, $headers);
    $responseArray = $okMessage;
   }
   else
   {
   //verification failed
   $responseArray = $errorMessage;
   }

    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
    }
    else {
    echo $responseArray;
    }
```

JS:

```
$(function () {

$('#contact-form').validator();

$('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {
    if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        var url = "contact.php";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data)
            {
                var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                var messageText = data.message;

                var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';
                if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                    $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                    $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                    grecaptcha.reset();
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
})
});
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: start by changing your input submit type to a button type.

Comment: have you check what you get return in `data` ? try to `alert(data)` or `console.log(data)`

Comment: Fred - not sure why that would make any difference. The form submits fine, it's just the success message which isn't displaying.

Comment: Ahmed - I'm not sure what you mean; I'm not good with these things, so if you could please elaborate, that would be great.

Comment: If you delete this whole if statement `if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {` and just echo responsearray the error/success message is shown

Answer (score 0):

Would:

```
if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                    $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                    $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                    grecaptcha.reset();
                }
```

this not clear the message you are trying to invoke?

since the class messages is the first child on "#contact-form" would it not always reset the messages you put in immediately, after putting in the data in the line before?

Also, why aren't you just toggling a modal or a popup instead of injecting an entire div dynamically? this seems like a lot of work, for something that could be done more easily with pre-loaded html? Or am I missing something obvious?

I am assuming of course that the alert, is the "success" message. But why call it an alert in your code? Why not call it successmessage? Using proper terminology will help yourself and others read your code later ;)

There is an option in the ajax method to have seperate functions for failures and successes.

I hope I helped, even if I am wrong about why you don't see your text.

try adding

```
if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                    alert("Test");
                    $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                    $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                    grecaptcha.reset();
                }
```

Comment: Hi Morten, thank you for looking over this. However, I'm still a beginner and don't really understand the response. Do you have some suggestions of what the php / js should look like? Thanks

Comment: simply remove this line:
 $('#contact-form')[0].reset();

Comment: try to add an alert, in the success function that just reads "test" or something. To verify that you are even hitting the succes criteria.

Comment: Hi Morten - As I said, I'm really a beginner, so I wouldn't know where to start with your suggestion. If you have two minutes and could show me exactly what code I need to add / remove, that would be amazing. Thanks

Comment: @JoeFlaherty I have edittd my answer to include the code snippet I suggested. if a pop-up appears that says "Test" and then you can click okay to cancel it, you know that your php bit executed without failure. If however it does not. Either the ajax isn't being executed, or you have an error in your php bit.